# regex to allow one comma and not at the start or end of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very good at regex and I need 3 different regex's that follow the following rules:

1. I need a regex that only allows one comma in string
2. I need a regex that doesn't allow a comma at the start of a string but still allow only one comma.
3. I need a regex that doesn't allow a comma at the end of a string but still allow only one comma.

For the first rule: `21, day` would be okay but `21, day, 32` would not be okay.

For the second rule: `,21` would not be okay.

For the third rule: `21,` would not be okay.

So far I have created a regex below which accommodates for the rules above but I was wondering if it could be split up into three different regex's that can accommodate for the three above rules.

```
^[a-z0-9A-Z&.\/'_ ]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9&.\/'_ ]+)?$
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Sample input and output would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Allow only one comma (put a `?` behind the second comma if you want to make the comma optional):

```js
        ^[^,]*,[^,]*$
```

2. Allow only one comma but none at the beginning:

```js
        ^[^,]+,[^,]*$
```

3. Allow only one comma but none at the end:

```js
        ^[^,]*,[^,]+$
```

`[^,]` means "a character that is not a comma".

Comment: *-Modifier allows for matching zero characters

Comment: Sure, why not? He didn't specify that something MUST be before or after the comma. Where there has to be something except the comma I specify it explicitly. That's the correct way for this case.

Comment: When zero characters are before the comma, the comma is at the beginning: Rule 2

Comment: Every regex has different rules, he doesn't want a regex that matches for all three rules. :)

Comment: Oh misunderstood the question, yeah

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Its case sensitive. can anyone help me making it case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the job.

```
^[^,]+,[^,]+$
```

Explanation:

`[^,]+` -> Not comma at least once

`,` -> comma (obviously)

`[^,]+` -> Not comma at least once (again)

Answer (score 0):

1. [`^(?!.*,.*,)`](https://regex101.com/r/VZasni/1/) - this is the base regex rejecting recurrent commas.
2. [`^(?!,)(?!.*,.*,)`](https://regex101.com/r/Yk44aL/1) - the same base with added "no comma at the start" condition
3. [`^(?!.*,.*,).*(?:[^,]|^)$`](https://regex101.com/r/QtGSU8/1) - the same base with "no comma at the end". The latter is implemented as alternation group match since lookbehinds are not available in JavaScript.

Note: all these patterns allow zero or one comma in the input. If you need strictly one comma, prepend each of them with `^(?=.*,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple string operations can handle this:

```js
function testForComma(str) {
    //Comma isn't first character
    //Comma only exists once
    //Comma isn't last character
    return str.indexOf(',') >= 1 &&
        str.lastIndexOf(',') == str.indexOf(',') &&
        str.lastIndexOf(',') != str.length - 1;
}
console.log(testForComma(','));
console.log(testForComma(', '));
console.log(testForComma(' ,'));
console.log(testForComma(' , '));
console.log(testForComma(' ,, '));
```

Answer (score 0):

simple expression is like -  ^[^,]+,[^,]+$