# Regex exclude characters at start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm [trying to select](https://regex101.com/r/O4TaEY/1) all `[a-z',]` symbols but exclude commas at start and end. Keep only the selection inside the red rect. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: Use lookarounds.

Comment: There are commas I'd like to keep in the rect. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538558/regex-to-allow-one-comma-and-not-at-the-start-or-end-of-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is an optional capturing group repeating zero or more times:

```
[a-z](?:[',]*[a-z]+)*
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O4TaEY/4)

- `[a-z]` - A character in the range a-z.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group.

  - `[',]*` - Zero or more characters from the specified character class.
  - `[a-z]+` - At least one character in the range a-z.
  - `)*` - Close non-capturing group and match it zero or more times.

---

[image]

<sup>**Note:** If for good reasons OP's intention was to match a quote at the very end, we can add an optional apostrophe: `[a-z](?:[',]*[a-z]+'?)*`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/O4TaEY/7)</sup>

Comment: This is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could first replace the commas in question and select the characters you want afterwards:

```js
let string = `,,."?!tats,t'ats,t,s',l,f,%$,`;

string = string.replace(/^,|,$/g, "~ooo~");
console.log(string);
```

In other languages you could use lookarounds (a negative lookbehind and a positive lookahead, that is).

Comment: @F.Vosnim: You can choose anything you want, it must only occur once. E.g. the characters `~ooo~` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You could match with the following regular expression.

```
[a-z'](?:[a-z',]*[a-z'])?
```

Start your engine!

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
[a-z']      : match one character in character class
(?:         : begin non-capture group
  [a-z',]*  : match 0+ characters in character class
  [a-z']    : match one character in character class
)           : end non-capture group
?           : optionally match non-capture group
```